# Exclude contacts from report based on membership they have

Tags: civimember, joomla, custom-reports

I want to make a report that only shows contacts that **don't have** any of the listed membership id.

The following SQL code filters the memberships, but still lists contacts that have other memberships, including the ones I want to avoid (e.g.: it shows *Joe* with a membership type 8, but *Joe* also have another membership of type 7, so I want to exclude *Joe* from the report).

When trying to make this with Search Builder I got the same situation.

I'm using Joomla! on that, so Drupal Views are **not** an option. I have the last CiviCrm version.

> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_sort_name, contact_civireport.id as civicrm_contact_id, membership_civireport.membership_type_id as civicrm_membership_membership_type_id, membership_civireport.join_date as civicrm_membership_join_date, mem_status_civireport.name as civicrm_membership_status_name
>
> FROM  civicrm_contact contact_civireport 
>                  INNER JOIN civicrm_membership membership_civireport
>                             ON contact_civireport.id =
>                                membership_civireport.contact_id AND membership_civireport.is_test = 0
>
> LEFT JOIN civicrm_membership_status mem_status_civireport
>                             ON mem_status_civireport.id =
>                                membership_civireport.status_id
>
> WHERE ( mem_status_civireport.id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) )
>
> ORDER BY contact_civireport.sort_name, contact_civireport.id, membership_civireport.membership_type_id
>
> LIMIT 0, 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to make a Smart Group (A) of those with Membership X or Y or Z, then have another Smart Group with the larger target group eg All Individuals (B), then use the Custom 'Include / Exclude' Search to do B not A.

This may not help you if your need an sql query but could be useful to others (if it works as I expect it would)

Answer (score 2):

From the description it seems you need to filter the report using type id whereas the query applies the condition on `membership_status_id`. You may also need a subquery to address this -

Instead of

```
WHERE ( mem_status_civireport.id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) )
```

try removing the contacts from the query itself which has those `membership_type_id`. Something like -

```
WHERE (contact_civireport.id NOT IN (
  SELECT contact.id 
  FROM civicrm_contact as contact 
    INNER JOIN civicrm_membership membership
      ON contact.id = membership.contact_id 
      AND membership.is_test = 0 
  WHERE membership.membership_type_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)))
```

This will remove any contact having `membership_type_id` in the ids provided.